# WP7 Tombstoning - cannot set list selected item value from State data

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, tombstoning

I am setting up tombstoning for a simple WP7 app. I have a list of items, and I want to save the ListBox.SelectedIndex in State memory, and on returning to the page, have that item selected in the list.

When I try the following code, saving the value seems to work (I have confirmed by displaying it in a MessageBox) but the list item is not selected.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

            if (State.ContainsKey("activeResult"))
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(State["activeResult"]);
            }
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            State["activeResult"] = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        }
```

The code compiles with no errors - but the listbox item is just never selected.
thanks for your help!
cheers
Will

Comment: how are you determining if it is selected? Have you added a handler for SelectionChanged, to see if that gets called? When do you populate the listbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wild guess says you're databinding the List **after** you set the `SelectedIndex`, and as such it have no effect (unless it's zero).

Solution: Ensure your ViewModel is initialized, and loaded before you set the `SelectedIndex`, or databind the `SelectedIndex` property, and set it on your ViewModel, rather than on the UI component.

Comment: you were right - after much debugging I discovered that I was indeed databinding the List after setting the SelectedIndex. Not a bad guess, given how much of the code was pasted above!